# MySQL separate and select values from one value field

Tags: mysql, separator

I have the following:

`id | value

1 | abc:432:xyz

2 | 678:123:iop`

And like to get:

`id | valueA | valueB | valueC 

1 | abc | 432 | xyz

2 | 678 | 123 | iop`

Is this possible by sql query?
Thx!

Comment: Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using sql query:

```
SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`, ':', 1) AS valueA ,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,':',2),':',-1) AS valueB ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,':',-2),':',-1) AS valueC 
FROM   tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to separate them after you read the query results!

Query:

```
$this->db->query("select id, value from tablename");
```

Example in PHP (Could be anything):

```
foreach($resultRecord as $record){
    $segment = explode(":",$record->value);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$record->id;
    for($i=0;$i<count($segment);i++){
       echo "<td>".$segment[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`, ':', 1) as valueA, 
       SUBSTRING(`value`,5,3) as valueB, 
       SUBSTRING(`value`,9) as valueC 
          FROM Table_name
```

use above query.

Answer (score 0):

use this

create table test2 as SELECT id,substr(value,1,3) as valueA,substr(value,5,3) as valueB,substr(value,9,3) as valueC FROM `test`